# Memory management in javascript jquery mobile with phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, memory-management, cordova

I'm building a jquery mobile + phonegap app to bundle for iOS. The JQM site/app works as it should on a web browser. However, when bundled with phonegap and tested on a phone, it seems to forget javascript functions. 
For example, I open/close panels on swipe. After a couple of swipes, ~10 opens/closes, it no longer responds to a swipe. I cannot open a panel. Other buttons are still functional, but I cant get the panel.

On a computer or webapp, I can do it all day long without it freezing up. Is there possibly something clearing functions from my javascript? Or should I define them in a different way?

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page', function() {
  $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#page", function(e) {
    console.log('swiped!!')
  });
});
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Apparently it only "forgets" the function when I do it consistently back-and-forth for the ~10 tries. If I leave a ~2-3 second pause between each swipe, it seems to work fine for a lot longer. Maybe the new swipe events are occurring while the older swipe event is still completing the function??? And that is causing them to get tangled up and freeze? I've been kind of stuck on this. Any help/insight on memory management of phonegap app's javascript would be nice.

Comment: If you remove `pageinit` event, I guess it will work with no issues. Try it.

Comment: That broke it even more. It wouldnt work at all, bc jqm wasnt loaded yet. But even when I wrapped it in `$(function() {})` , it behaved similarly -- worked for a couple of swipes then stops/forgets. Its very weirddd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found a fix.

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page', function() {
 $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#page", function(e) {
   console.log('swiped!!')
 });
});
```

This was the psuedo code I posted. It turns out, the console.log msg was getting called on every swipe, but the panel open/close calls that were omitted in the above code, were not.

Here's the complete old code:

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#page', function(){
  $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#page", function(e) {
    console.log('swiped!!')
    // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
    // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
    // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open") {
      if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
        $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      }
    }
    else if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) == "open"){
      $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "close" );
      $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "close" );
    }
  });
}
```

These changes fixed the code:
took the selector off the swipeleft swiperight function
`$(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", "#page", function(e) {}` became `$(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {}`
and I added `e.stopPropagation()` on the event. I think it must've been JQM event propagation bubbling up the DOM and breaking everything.

```
    $(document).on('pageinit', '#page', function() {
  $(document).on("swipeleft swiperight", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log('swiped!!')
    // We check if there is no open panel on the page because otherwise
    // a swipe to close the left panel would also open the right panel (and v.v.).
    // We do this by checking the data that the framework stores on the page element (panel: open).
    if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) !== "open") {
      if ( e.type === "swipeleft"  ) {
        $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      } else if ( e.type === "swiperight" ) {
        $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "open" );
      }
    }
    else if ($.mobile.activePage.jqmData( "panel" ) == "open"){
      $( "#left-panel" ).panel( "close" );
      $( "#right-panel" ).panel( "close" );
    }
  });
    }
```